# KivyMD: An independent Login screen and MDBottomNavigation

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I would like to have my Login Screen as a default screen for when application starts.
After a user signs in the screen manager should switch to the Home screen, which is a part of my MDBottomNavigation (and the Login Screen is not!).

Basically, I'm trying to make the Login screen independent from the MDBottomNavigation... and I can't.
Right now at the start I see both the Login screen and the Home screen with the MDBottomNavigation.

In the future, I'm planning to have other screens, which should be accessed in particular situations but not from the MDBottomNavigation. I'm very new to both kivy and kivymd, would appreciate any help!

Here is my main.py:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation import MDBottomNavigationItem
import requests
import json
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

# the Root
class BL(MDBoxLayout):
   pass

# screens
class LoginScreen(Screen):
   pass

class HomeScreen(MDBottomNavigationItem):
   pass

class OrdersScreen(MDBottomNavigationItem):
   pass

class ClientsScreen(MDBottomNavigationItem):
   pass

class AccountScreen(MDBottomNavigationItem):
   pass


class MainApp(MDApp):

def log_in(self, username, password):
    log_in_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/"
    log_in_data = {"username": username, "password": password}
    log_in_request = requests.post(log_in_url, data=log_in_data)
    response_data = json.loads(log_in_request.content.decode())
    if log_in_request.ok:
        token = response_data["token"]
        with open("token.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(token)
        user_id = response_data["user_id"]

def change_screen(self, screen_name):
    screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
    screen_manager.current = screen_name

def build(self):
    return BL()

MainApp().run()
```

Here is the main.kv

```
#: include kv/loginscreen.kv
#: include kv/homescreen.kv
#: include kv/ordersscreen.kv
#: include kv/clientsscreen.kv
#: include kv/accountscreen.kv

<BL>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    id: bl

    LoginScreen:
        name: "login_screen"
        id: login_screen

    MDBottomNavigation:
        id: screen_manager

        HomeScreen:
            name: "home_screen"
            id: home_screen

        OrdersScreen:
            name: "orders_screen"
            id: orders_screen

        ClientsScreen:
            name: "clients_screen"
            id: clients_screen

        AccountScreen:
            name: "account_screen"
            id: account_screen
```

loginscreen.kv:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    text: "Login"
    icon: "login"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDTextField:
            id: username
            hint_text: "Username"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        MDTextField:
            id: password
            password: True
            hint_text: "Password"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Sign In"
            on_release:
                app.log_in(username.text, password.text)
                app.change_screen("home_screen")
```

homescreen.kv:

```
<HomeScreen>:
    text: "Home"
    icon: "home"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDLabel:
            text: "SM-COMMERCE APP Main"
            halign: "center"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ScreenManager`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) to make two separated screen. One screen for your login screen and another one for your `MDBottomNavigation`:

```
<BL>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    id: bl

    ScreenManager:
        id: auth_screenmanager
        LoginScreen:
            name: "login_screen"
            id: login_screen
        
        Screen:
            name: 'dashboard'
            MDBottomNavigation:
            id: screen_manager

                HomeScreen:
                    name: "home_screen"
                    id: home_screen

        ### add more screens in future
```

main.py:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        # check if the user is already logged in then 'dashboard' will show up
        # else redirect to 'login_screen'
```

Comment: Cannot start the app, I'm getting the following error:       19:            name: 'dashboard'
      20:            MDBottomNavigation:
 >>   21:            id: dashboard
      22:                HomeScreen:
      23:                    name: "home_screen"
 ...
 Invalid data after declaration